# Split two lists of lists into subgraphs using python

Tags: python

I have a network as a list of lists, where the first list is the origin nodes and the second list is the destination nodes, and then the two lists combined tell you which origins have an edge to which destinations.

So essentially I have this:

```
edge_index = [[0,1,2,3,5,6,5,9,10,11,12,12,13],[1,2,3,4,6,7,8,10,11,10,13,12,9]]
```

And I want to split this list structure into:

```
[[0,1,2,3,5,6,5],[9,10,11,12,12,13]]
[[1,2,3,4,6,7,8],[10,11,10,13,12,9]]
```

i.e. there is no link between 8 and 9, so it's a new subgraph.

I cannot use networkx because it does not seem to give me the right number of subgraphs (I know how many networks there should be in advance). So I wanted to subgraph the list using a different method, and then see if I get the same number as NetworkX or not.

I wrote this code:

```
edge_index = [[0,1,2,3,5,6,5],[1,2,3,4,6,7,8]]
origins_split = edge_index[0]
dest_split = edge_index[1]

master_list_of_all_graph_nodes = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]  ##for testing
list_of_graph_nodes = []
list_of_origin_edges = []
list_of_dest_edges = []

graph_nodes = []
graph_edge_origin = []
graph_edge_dest = []
targets_list = []


for o,d in zip(origins_split,dest_split): #change
    if o not in master_list_of_all_graph_nodes:
        if d not in master_list_of_all_graph_nodes:
            nodes = [o,d]
            origin = [o]
            dest = [d]
            graph_nodes.append(nodes)
            graph_edge_origin.append(origin)
            graph_edge_dest.append(dest)



        elif d in master_list_of_all_graph_nodes:
            for index,graph_node_list in enumerate(graph_nodes):
                if d in graph_node_list:
                    origin_list = graph_edge_origin[index]
                    origin_list.append(o)
                    dest_list.append(d)
                    master_list_of_all_graph_nodes.append(o)
    


    if d not in master_list_of_all_graph_nodes:
        if o in master_list_of_all_graph_nodes:
            for index,graph_node_list in enumerate(graph_nodes):
                if o in graph_node_list:
                    origin_list = graph_edge_origin[index]
                    origin_list.append(o)
                    dest_list.append(d)
                    master_list_of_all_graph_nodes.append(d)


    if o in master_list_of_all_graph_nodes:
        if d in master_list_of_all_graph_nodes:

            o_index = ''
            d_index = ''
            for index,graph_node_list in enumerate(graph_nodes):
                if d in graph_node_list:
                    d_index = index
                if o in graph_node_list:
                    o_index = index
            
            if o_index == d_index:
                graph_edge_origin[o_index].append(o)
                graph_edge_dest[d_index].append(d)
                master_list_of_all_graph_nodes.append(o)
                master_list_of_all_graph_nodes.append(d)


            else:
                o_list = graph_edge_origin[o_index]
                d_list = graph_edge_dest[d_index]

                node_o_list = node_list[o_index]
                node_d_list = node_list[d_index]
                new_node_list = node_o_list + node_d_list

                node_list.remove(node_o_list)
                node_list.remove(node_d_list)
                graph_edge_origin.remove(o_list)
                graph_edge_dest.remove(d_list)
                new_origin_list = o_list.append(o)
                new_dest_list = d_list.append(d)
                graph_nodes.append(new_node_list)
                graph_edge_dest.append(new_dest_list)
                graph_edge_origin.append(new_origin_list)
                master_list_of_all_graph_nodes.append(o)
                master_list_of_all_graph_nodes.append(d)

print(graph_nodes)
print(graph_edge_dest)
print(graph_edge_origin)
```

And i get the error:

```
    graph_edge_origin[o_index].append(o)
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I was wondering if someone could demonstrate where I'm going wrong, but also I feel like I'm doing this really inefficiently so if someone could demonstrate a better method I'd appreciate it. I can see other questions like this, but not one I can specifically figure out how to apply here.

Comment: To be honest I find the explanation on the logic of what are you trying to do rather lacking.

Comment: You probably need to simplify the example and provide us with an expected output. For instance, I do not see an edge between `4` and `5` but they are together in the output. Why?

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
graph_edge_origin[o_index].append(o)
```

o_index is a string (probably the empty string, due to the for-loop not being entered).

In general either set a break-point on the line that is failing and inspect the variables in your debugger, or print out the variables before the failing line.